# DropDownList tooltip in Chrome and Safari

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, tooltip

To add a tooltip to my DropDownList items I have

```
      DropDownList1.Items[i].Attributes.Add("title", tooltip);
```

Problem is this doesn't work in Chrome and Safari.  Any other way to add a tooltip, or any way to fix this in Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tooltip components, also jQuery has a number of plug-ins that can offer this kind of functionality. I know what you are suffering as the tooltips appear as expected in IE but in Chrome/Safari they tend to be blank boxes. It'll be interesting to see if anyone else has a fix for that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the ToolTip property of the dropdown list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.tooltip.aspx

Comment: He's looking for a tooltip on each individual item in the dropdown, not on the whole dropdown itself.

Comment: Ah. I didn't get that part. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
// Assign Tooltip value on click of dropdown list  //    
  $(document).ready(function () {
    try{  
     $('select').click(function (el) {    
         $(this).find("option:[title='']").each(function (el) {       
                                   $(this).attr("title",$(this).text());
         })                
      });
    }
    catch(e)
{
    alert(e);
}
```

})